# Filter a tableview in Titanium?

Tags: uitableview, filter, titanium, titanium-mobile

I've been trying to implement client-side filtering of a tableview in Titanium without success.

I've got three buttons that are displayed in the Navigation bar that when clicked need to filter the table view rows.

The problem is not deciding which row to show/hide it's the actual code to hide/show a row.

Titanium API docs for [TableViewRow](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.7.3/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow-object) list show() and hide() methods but they don't see to work.

I can use the tableview's deleteRow method to delete the row but that means it also gets removed from the datasource which makes it impossible to show again without reloading the tableview data from the remote datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would filter on the data you have in your tableview and assign the filtered data to the tableview each time you want to filter like that:

```
myData = applyMyCustomFilterOnData(myData);
tableview.setData(myData);
```

Comment: Looks like I may have to go down this route. Was trying to avoid it for a less resource intensive route.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds silly and should be identical behavior, but have you tried the visible property instead of show() and hide()?

There are quite a few quirks in Ti, and this may be one of those small inconsistencies.  We had this issue on some object or other a while back, it may have even been the TableViewRow.

Comment: Same here, I invoke hide and show methods on TableViewRow objects but it doesn't seem to have any effect.